# Symfony 2 set Request content and retrieve it

Tags: php, json, symfony

I am working in Symfony2 and I want to se the content of a Request with a JSON string and use i.e.: `$request->get('name')` to access the content.

JSON string:

```
$string = '{
            "name":"Bob",
            "surname":"White",
            "email":"bobwhite@gmail.com",
            "nationality":"",
        }';

$request = new Request ($query = array(), $request = array(), $attributes = array(), $cookies = array(), $files = array(), $server = array(), $content = $string);

var_dump($request->get('name'));die;
```

To me the above is a valid way but the var dump gives me null... can anyone see where I m going wrong here...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this?

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$input = '{
            "name":"Bob",
            "surname":"White",
            "email":"bobwhite@gmail.com",
            "nationality":""
        }';
$data = json_decode($input, true);


$request = new Request (array(), $data);

var_dump($request->request->get('name'));

die;
```

Comment: I agree, this is the way to do it. Alternatively, he could use `JsonResponse` class to eliminate the first `array()` arg.

Comment: @JovanPerovic no it will only accept PHP arrays. public function __construct(array $query = array(), array $request = array(), ...

Comment: Ah, that is true. I misread the code, as I usually do `json_decode($input, true)`. The second argument `true` tells `json_decode` to return `array` instead of `stdClass`

Comment: @JovanPerovic ah yes, changed it to return arrays. :)